Real Gaussian beam quality factor and refractive index
To describe a real Gaussian beam, do I have to take both the quality factor $M^2$ and refractive index $n$ into account? I'm asking this because every source I've come across always leaves at least one of them out of the equation.
$$z_R=\frac{\pi n w_0^2}{M^2\lambda}.$$

Could you show an example of a source not including both terms?

ior for air is 1.0003 .....

My guess is that they're either assuming an ideal beam so $M^2$ is 1, or assuming air.
